# Mongodb Bson type to Json

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I am testing my asp.net core 2.2 web api with Postman. I write the JSON manually like this (httppatch):

```
{
    "query": "{\"name\": \"foo\"}",

    "update": [ "{\"$set\":{\"name\":\"foo2\"}}","{\"$set\":{\"path\": \"foo2 path\"}}" ]
}
```

Now I am thinking how can I build the patch body on the client side.
My question is how can I get the equivalent of this code in json to make it look like the one I write manually?

```
var query = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(e => e.name, "foo");
var updates = Builders<T>.Update.Set(e => e.name, "foo2").Set(e => e.Path, "foo2 path");
```

I guess it's all about serialization, any idea how can I make it?

--**Update**--

I found this:

```
var serializerRegistry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
var documentSerializer = serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
var upList = updates.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);
```

<s>but it grabs only the last set</s> it combines all sets in one (*My bad, thanks to @Simon Mourier to pointing out my mistake !*)

Comment: `Builders<T>.Update.Set(e => e.name, "foo2").Set(e => e.Path, "foo2 path").ToJson()` 
 you tried this?

Comment: I try that and getting this: '"{ \"_t\" : \"CombinedUpdateDefinition`1\" }"'

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you creating a webAPI endpoint that takes a json representation of a mongo query/update and executing it against a mongod without any sort of validation?

Comment: @PeteGarafano I do a little validation, from FindOneAndUpdateOptions I set the BypassDocumentValidation to false and just before that I do BsonDocument.Parse(update[i]) for each string in the update array to validate the string. I guess it's not a complete validation... What you think ?

Comment: While MongoDB isn't susceptible to traditional SQL injection, and API like this is susceptible to potentially big problems with unvalidated input. For example `{ "query": "{\"_id\": { $exists: true }", "update": \"{ \"a\": 2}"}` would replace every document in the collection the update is run against to contain just an `_id` and a field `a` with a value of 2. As with any API, *never* trust the input.

Comment: The code in your comment is correct. It doesn't only grab the last set, it combines both sets into this: `{ "$set" : { "name" : "foo2", "path" : "foo2 path" } }` which is expected.

Comment: @Simon you are right, I was testing with duplicate name and this is why I was getting just the last one. Do you have any complete solution ?

Comment: Well, you have a complete solution, Render is the method that outputs into Bson/Json, etc. It exists on all constructs that you can build with C#. What more do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution:

**On the client side**

```
        // serializer
        var serializerRegistry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var documentSerializer = serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();

        // filter and update
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(e => e.Level, 2);
        var updates = Builders<T>.Update
                     .Set(e => e.Name, "foo2")
                     .Set(e => e.Path, "foo2 path")
                     .Inc(e => e.Level, 1);

        // get the string of the filter and the update
        var filterString = filter.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);
        var updateString = updates.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);

        // instantiate patch object with properties to json
        Patch patch = new Patch()
        {
            Query = filterString.ToJson(),
            Update = updateString.ToJson()
        };

        // patch object to json
        var patchJson = patch.ToJson();
```

**On the server side**

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchOne([FromBody]Patch patch)
    {
        // don't need to ModelState.isValid, it's done on binding
        
        try
        {
            var update = BsonDocument.Parse(patch.Update);
            var filter = BsonDocument.Parse(patch.Query);

            var result = await _serviceBase.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
            
            ...

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message.ToJson());
        }
    }
```

**Global Modals (my solution structure)**

```
public class Patch
{
    [Required]
    public string Query { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Update { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I Find a way to see the query

you need make the query and save it in var

```
var query = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(e => e.name, "foo");
var makeQuery = _collection.Find(query).ToString();
```

makeQuery have the value of Filter.Eq